# How to filtter multiple Table data (coming from API) using checkbox in angular 2 or js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, search, filter

here I have attached a demo of Redbus, like bus data coming after clicking varieties of checkboxes, I need that type of filter in angular 2.

in my case, the data is coming from API  and stored in multiple table format.I need to filter multiple tables.

so,I need when I will select some checkboxes it will filter the data from the table.

```
enter code here/checkboxes starts here check i have taken bus and fare as demo bcoz its fetching from api
<div class="filter2"  id="myUL">
              <div class="search">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder=""  id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">
              </div>
              <label class="containe" >fare
                <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label><br/>
 <label class="containe" >bus
                <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label><br/>

            </div>

//table starts here

<table class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-bus-table " >   <!-- search result table -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let bus of this.global.getSearchResult.data.onwardSearch "> <!--| filter:this.vehicleClassArr  or | filter:bus.vehicleClass search results container -->
      <tr class="busrow">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-1 col-lg-1 busdiv-pad">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 bus-details">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 buslogo">
              <img src="assets/img/bus1.svg" height=44px width=44px>
              <div class="rating-circle">5.0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
              <table class="wd-100 bus-table" >
                <tr>
                  <td class="wd-30 busname"><p>{{bus.operatorName}}<span class="gps">GPS</span></p></td>  <!-- Bus name -->
                  <td class="wd-30 timing"><p>{{bus.departureTime}} <img src="assets/img/to1.svg"> {{bus.arrivalTime}}</p></td> <!-- Bus time -->
                  <td class="wd-20 seats-left"><p>Total Seats : {{bus.availableSeats}}</p></td>   <!-- Bus available seats -->
                  <td class="wd-20 price"><p><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>{{bus.fare}}</p></td>   <!-- Bus fare -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="wd-30 bustype"><p>{{bus.vehicleClass}}</p></td>    <!-- Bus type -->
                  <td class="wd-30 distance"><p>06h 30m/340km</p></td>  <!-- Bus total distance -->
                  <td class="wd-20 windowseats"><p>1 Window</p></td>    <!-- Bus total window seats -->
                  <td class="wd-20 revisedprice"><p><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>{{bus.fare}}</p></td>    <!-- Bus revised fare -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance.Hope You can solve my Issue.

here a picture of the Redbus filter example.

[image: Redbus filter example]

Comment: filter the data of the table ? Can you give us an example ? The question is not clear enough to say what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

first save the input content into variables

```
searchVar: string = '';
checkboxVarOne: string = '';
check...
```

seccond you need to do is Pipes:

here an example

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: any, inputString: string): any {
 if  (!inputString) {return value}
  let solution = value.filter(v => {
   if ( !v.ubicacion ) {return }
    return  v.ubicacion.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputString.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  })
 return solution;
 }

}
```

And do the same thing for all type of values, then use all pipes in this way:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let bus of this.global.getSearchResult.data.onwardSearch | searchPipe: searchVar | checkboxPipeOne: checkboxVarOne">
```

And that's all. I hope I was clear.

Comment: I am trying it and will let you know.

Comment: any plunker example for sorting multiple tables in angular 2?